# Is it possible to pick up any library from the Maven repository and use into Quarkus app

Tags: quarkus

I am new to the Quarkus, Is it possible to pick up any library from the Maven repository and use into Quarkus app.
or i can only use these  [Code](https://code.quarkus.io/).

Is there any impact on performance?

Answer (score 4):

If you plan on building a Java app deployed on the JVM, you should be able to use any library.

Things are a bit different if you plan to build a native executable. In this case, a library might need some additional metadata for GraalVM. That's one of the things we do in our Quarkus extensions.

Comment: i wanted to use JOOQ in Quarkus, is there any alternative available in Quarkus?